# NameError - 'name not defined' in custom user function for importing files

Tags: python, nameerror

pretty new to Python. I have several custom user functions in my Python script, however one, which I use for importing files, isn't quite working and I get the error.

> NameError - name 'filename' not defined'

The function goes as follows:

```
def importdata(path,temp_file_name,dataset_name):
    temp_file_name = os.path.join('..', 'data', path)
    dataset_name = pd.read_csv(temp_file_name, index_col='time')
    var1, var2, var3, var4 = dataset_name.keys()
```

When I then try to call it using

```
importdata('File.csv',filename,datasetname)
```

I get the NameError on 'filename'.

I have tried defining it elsewhere, globally, using a Class, using 'filename' etc, but to no avail. This problem seems to occur a lot, but none of the solutions I can find seem to work for me. Is it possible to have such a function for the code provided and if so, how can I make it work?

EDIT:
It worked when I didn't use the custom function, but only

`filename = os.path.join('..', 'data', 'File.csv')
   datasetname = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='time')
   var1, var2, var3, var4 = datasetname.keys()`

EDIT2:
I managed to get it working now, thanks to the advices below. The working code now looks as following:

```
def importdata(*paths):
    for index, path in enumerate(paths):
       temp_file_name = os.path.join('..', 'data', path)
       data[index] = pd.read_csv(temp_file_name, index_col=' Time_Created')
       data[index].index = pd.to_datetime(data[index].index, unit='ms')

       global var1, var2, var3, var4
       var1, var2, var3, var4  = data[index].keys()
```

Comment: You haven't posted the relevant code. For all we know, neither `filename` or `datasetname` are defined. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The function expects three arguments: path, temp_file_name and dataset_name.  When you call 
importdata('File.csv',filename,datasetname) it looks like you are passing "file.csv" as the path, rather than a path to a file. Have you assigned values to filename and datasetname which you also pass to the function?

Comment: Why do you take ``temp_file_name`` as a parameter but immediately overwrite it?